# Gammu SMS TextDecoded field are separated

Tags: php, mysql, field, gammu

In my country there are 3 mobile service operators, and when I send one SMS from two of they, the Gammu daemon table `inbox` shows the `TextDecoded` field separated in 2 or 3 parts, and that tuples show a some kind of numeration in the `UDH` field, but just when the SMS text is too long, like more of 130 characters, something like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| *UDH*        |     *Text*     |
+-------------------------------+
| 050003B90301 | Hi my name is A|
+-------------------------------+
| 050003B90302 | rmin and I wan |
+-------------------------------+
| 050003B90303 | t be your frien|
+-------------------------------+
```

I don't know if exist a configuration for correct that.
I'm working with MySQL.

Comment: what the problem ? what do you want ? explain a bit more please ;)

Comment: The messages should be merged by Gammu if they arrive within reasonable timeframe (configurable by [MultipartTimeout](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html#option-MultipartTimeout)). You can certainly figure out what is going on from the Gammu log (see https://wammu.eu/support/bugs/).